# Estoy teniendo serias dudas en como plantear y hacer este ejercicio.(fechas)

Tags: java

Realizar un programa que lea una fecha y calcule el número de días que quedan hasta fin de año.
He estado viendo por la red que se deberia utilizar calendar, calendar gregoria y simpledataformat.
Saludos a todos y gracias de

Comment: ¿Qué has hecho hasta el momento? Para calcular una fecha puedes hacerlo fácilmente con `LocalDate` luego con el método `until` puedes calcular la diferencia de una fecha. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: Gracias, me mirare lo que me pasaste ;)

Comment: Hola @Kaly9Comotuvea , por que aún no has leido [ask] y realizado el [tour]?, es importante para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio ,saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debemos de tener en cuenta varias cosas, la primera es saber si el año es bisiesto o no, para ello tendremos el siguiente código que tan solo tenemos que pasarle el año:

```
public static boolean esBisiesto(int anio) {

    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    boolean esBisiesto = false;
    if (calendar.isLeapYear(anio)) {
        esBisiesto = true;
    }
    return esBisiesto;

}
```

Una vez sepamos si el año es bisiesto o no, tendremos que tratar la fecha desde la que partimos, para ello debemos de recoger el día, el mes y el año desde el que queremos empezar (en el ejemplo selecciono la fecha actual):

```
Date objDate = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat objSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    String fechaAct = objSDF.format(objDate);
```

Esto nos dará la fecha en formato 11-12-2019. Ahora debemos separar los datos para tratarlos y traducirlos a días (excluyendo el día), para ello:

```
String[] fechaSplit = fechaAct.split("-");

    int dia = Integer.parseInt(fechaSplit[0]);
    int mes = Integer.parseInt(fechaSplit[1]);
    int anyo = Integer.parseInt(fechaSplit[2]);
```

Ahora comenzamos con el tratado del mes para convertirlo en días, para ello iremos comprobando en qué mes nos encontramos y añadiendo los días de los meses que ya hemos pasado:

```
int days = 0;

    // Enero
    if(mes != 1) { days = days + 31; }
    // Febrero
    if(mes != 2) { 

        Date anioActual=new Date();
        if(esBisiesto(1900 + anioActual.getYear())){
            days= days + 29;
        }else{
            days= days + 28;
        }

    }
    // Marzo
    if(mes != 3) { days = days + 31; }
    // Abril
    if(mes != 4) { days = days + 30; }
    // Mayo
    if(mes != 5) { days = days + 31; }
    // Junio
    if(mes != 6) { days = days + 30; } 
    // Julio
    if(mes != 7) { days = days + 31; } 
    // Agosto
    if(mes != 8) { days = days + 31; } 
    // Septiembre
    if(mes != 9) { days = days + 30; } 
    // Octubre
    if(mes != 10) { days = days + 31; } 
    // Noviembre
    if(mes != 11) { days = days + 30; } 
    // Diciembre
    if(mes != 12) { days = days + 31; }
```

Esto nos dará los días transcurridos en el año, ahora debemos de comprobar cuantos años hay de diferencia:

```
int difAnyo = anyo - anyoInicio;

    int daysAnyosDif = difAnyo*365;
```

Por ultimo, lo que nos queda es sumar todos los resultados:

```
days = days + dia + daysAnyosDif;
```

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas usar la  clase `**Calendar**`. Aqui un ejemplo

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Today is " + today.getTime());
```

Si creas una para mes  y una para dia. Solo tienes que restar el dia 31 - el dia de hoy
y restar el mes 12 - mes actual

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, ayúdanos a responder preguntas que sean realizadas en base a lo definido en el [help], específicamente [ask] y ayudar al OP a mejorar sus preguntas, saludos.